# Priestly blessing with split minyan

Tags: health-safety-shmira, birchas-kohanim

This morning, a member of our synagogue raised an interesting question. Assume a congregation in Israel, which has to split the minyan in two in order to comply with precautionary measures due to the current coronavirus epidemic. There are two *kohanim* present. Should they go together, thus fulfilling literally the verse ([Bemidbar 6:23](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0406.htm#23)):

> דַּבֵּ֤ר אֶֽל־אַהֲרֹן֙ וְאֶל־בָּנָ֣יו לֵאמֹ֔ר כֹּ֥ה תְבָֽרְכ֖וּ אֶת־בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל אָמ֖וֹר לָהֶֽם׃
>
> Speak unto Aaron and unto his sons, saying: On this wise ye shall bless the children of Israel; ye shall say unto them.

Or should they go to two different *minyanim,* so both groups would receive the priestly blessing?

Please note that based on this verse say [Sotah](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=38&format=pdf) [38a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sotah.38a.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [Orach Chayim 138:10](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%97_%D7%99) that in case of a single *kohein* the prayer leader should not call *kohanim* aloud (to the contrary see [Yerushalmi Berakhot 5:4](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r1105.htm) and [Gittin 5:9](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r3505.htm)).

Comment: Here I fail to see the logic of Sotah, saying אמור להם refers to a plural from the _kohanim_ side. If you can help, I'd be happy to edit in.

Comment: If the 2 minyonim start at different times, the kohanim can go from one to the other and duchan at both.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok It wasn't the case, they had to decide it on the spot, and they didn't have time to wait and start later.